# How to expand a number in scientific notation in Jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So, let's say I have a long floating-point number stored in my database (ex: 0.00000003), but Jinja2 displays this number in scientific notation, which is bit awkward for what I'm expecting with my flask app. Is there any way to directly expand numbers in scientific notations in Jinja2, as we do in python using format:

```
number = 3e-08     
format(number, '.8f')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already giving the answer yourself. Use format on the number before you pass it to the template. Or use format in the template.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

number=3e-08

with app.app_context():
    render_template_string('{{s}}', s=format(number, '.8f'))

    render_template_string('{{ "%.8f"|format(d)}}', d=number)
```

Comment: I tried adding this line of code in my template: `<td>$ {{ ".8f"|format(current_user.main_balance) }}</td>` but it gives me a type error saying not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: You are missing the percentage.